# When to ask questions during online training - at the very end or at anytime throughout?

Tags: professionalism, communication, work-environment, ethics

I am attending training with several other team members. This training is online through Skype.

Typically, the trainer talks continuously for, say, 20-25 minutes. After this, he asks if anyone has any questions.

I find that I am often unable to follow the trainer, and once that starts to happen it snowballs, so I am quite lost by the end.

How do I deal with this situation, and what should I say to him if I want to get the most out of this training?

Is it okay to stop him and ask questions when I don't understand something, or should I wait and ask questions at the end? Alternatively, should I just try and "train myself" from online resources?

Comment: Why don't you ask the trainer instead of asking us? What makes you think that we on this site can read the trainer's mind? If the trainer discourages questions until the end, I'd tell him at the end "Here is where you lost us five minutes into your presentation" and it goes downhill for him from there as I keep ripping into him.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I have asked this question to know views of all good professionals members in this site to know what is best to do in this situation based on ethics as many other team members are also attending the training. I got some good answers from bharal and scaaahu and I appreciate their help on this. I think this is a question-answer forum to help someone who get stucked somewhere and want to know views on what best can be done at that situation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Ask questions continually.**

From my point of view, as someone who has *given* training, I would much rather be asked questions - no matter how stupid - throughout the training. I want the people listening to be trained, after all.

From my point of view as someone who has *been* trained, I find it a titanic waste of time if I don't understand something and then just sit and watch someone talk on about stuff. I also find that when I ask for clarification, people generally don't mind.

I'll note that this is only for *training* - when I might explain some new work I've done, I generally hate being asked questions, but that's just me, and I don't hold it against the *asker*.

As to how you ask - say "excuse me [trainer  name], I don't quite follow, could you go over that [whatever it was] one more time please?"

If the trainer refuses, well, you've got a rubbish trainer, and you should escalate to your manager that the trainer isn't very useful to you.

Comment: Do you want to say I should stop him as much time as I have query even he is continue with explaining things

Comment: @kulwal_amit i don't know what that means.

Comment: I mean to say should I interrupt him as many times as I want when he is continue with explaining other things to everyone

Comment: yes. but, uh, your phrasing is  really really bad. i know that "it is the same thing", but in life, phrasing is really important. In this case, it is an expression not just of what is needed, but the sentiment and reasoning behind it. *You ask for clarification as often as required* - yes. *You interrupt as many times as you want* - no. The former shows a desire to learn, and a collaborative approach. The latter will come across as self-centered and rude.

Comment: I understand what you want to say. Thanks for your help

Comment: +1 - interruptions also provide valuable feedback to the trainer that they maybe need to slow down or change their approach since their audience may be less skilled or differently skilled than anticipated.

Answer (score 5):

> I am attending training with 15 other team members

and

> Many times it happens that when he is explaining I am not getting what he said from the beginning and due to that I missed many of the more points also

Do other team members have the same problem?

If most of them have the same problem as you do, something is very wrong. Your trainer is wasting your team's and his precious time because the training sessions did not work.

I would talk to other team members to see what they feel about the training if I were you. If most (or many) of them feel the same way as you do, you need to talk to the trainer or your boss(manager) to see if there is any way to improve the training because this is not only your problem but also the whole team's. And the trainer needs to know about it.

Asking questions is of course one way of improvement in this case. You should ask the trainer when you feel that it's important for you (and other team members) to understand before he goes on to the next point. Another way is to prepare yourself before every session starts.

However, if only you (or only a few of your team members) have this problem, I would suggest you to work harder, like what you said in your question, understand more on this from online videos or tutorials, to get most out of this training. You still should ask questions if you feel it is **critical** for you to understand so that you can  work on your job later on.

Comment: Thanks scaaahu. What you said in last paragraph is what exactly I am doing now

Answer (score 1):

Ask the lecturer how they would prefer to handle questions. Some will want you to ask immediately, some have specific points in the presentation where questions would be appropriate, some prefer that you hold all questions to the end, and some would rather that you contact them one-on-one after the lecture is over.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are not receiving training online, you are attending a lecture via skype. Treat it essentially the same as any other training class. The mechanism for raising your hand and asking for clarification may be slightly different, but if you would have asked a question is a classroom with 15 students, then do the same in classroom environment.

Now if the class was truly online, where there was no instructor, then you would have a more difficult issue. But also have the ability to pause the training and use the resources of the internet to find the additional information you need.

Unless that instructor in the skype class is being paid just to read the PowerPoint slides to you, you are expected to ask questions.